# Read content of an XML invoice node

Tags: xml, vb.net, invoice

I am trying to read the content of an xml file that contains an electronic invoice. For this I use namespace but I have not been able to extract the data found in the cac:AdditionalItemProperty element and specifically the cbc:Name02</cbc:Name>cbc:Value2023171843</cbc:Value>
The code that I do is the following and additionally part of the xml. thanks for your help

File XML

```
<AttachedDocument xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:AttachedDocument-2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:CoreComponentTypeSchemaModule:2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#">
<ext:UBLExtensions>
...
</ext:UBLExtensions>
<cbc:UBLVersionID>UBL 2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:CustomizationID>Doctos</cbc:CustomizationID>
<cbc:ID>DT41647</cbc:ID>
<cbc:IssueDate>2023-03-17</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:ParentDocumentID>DT41647</cbc:ParentDocumentID>
<cac:SenderParty>
...
</cac:SenderParty>
<cac:ReceiverParty>
...
</cac:ReceiverParty>
<cac:Attachment>
<cac:ExternalReference>
<cbc:MimeCode>text/xml</cbc:MimeCode>
<cbc:EncodingCode>UTF-8</cbc:EncodingCode>
<cbc:Description>
<![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Invoice xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sts="xxxx" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:oth="http://example.org/oth" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"><ext:UBLExtensions><ext:UBLExtension><ext:ExtensionContent>
<sts:xxxExtensions><sts:InvoiceControl><sts:InvoiceAuthorization>99999999</sts:InvoiceAuthorization><sts:AuthorizationPeriod><cbc:StartDate>2023-02-23</cbc:StartDate><cbc:EndDate>2024-02-23</cbc:EndDate></sts:AuthorizationPeriod><cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cbc:Name>01</cbc:Name><cbc:Value>105584152</cbc:Value></cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cbc:Name>02</cbc:Name><cbc:Value>2023171843</cbc:Value></cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cac:AdditionalItemProperty><cbc:Name>03</cbc:Name><cbc:Value>184000</cbc:Value><cbc:ValueQuantity unitCode="KG">1280</cbc:ValueQuantity></cac:AdditionalItemProperty></cac:Item><cac:Price><cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PP">184000.00</cbc:PriceAmount><cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="94">1.00</cbc:BaseQuantity></cac:Price></cac:InvoiceLine></Invoice> ]]>
</cbc:Description>
</cac:ExternalReference>
</cac:Attachment>
<cac:ParentDocumentLineReference>
</cac:ParentDocumentLineReference>
</AttachedDocument>
```

'code VbNet

```
   m_xmld.Load(fileName)
   Dim manager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
   manager.AddNamespace("cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
   manager.AddNamespace("cac", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2")
   'manager.AddNamespace("qdt", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2")
   'manager.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
   'manager.AddNamespace("udt", "urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2")
   'manager.AddNamespace("ccts", "urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2")
   manager.AddNamespace("ext", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2")
   Dim list As XmlNodeList = m_xmld.SelectNodes("//cac:Attachment//cac:ExternalReference//cbc:Description", manager) 'da resultado 2
   'Dim nodeComprobante As XmlNode = m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("//cac:AdditionalItemProperty", manager)
   Dim nodeComprobante As XmlNode
   For Each Book As XmlNode In list
       nodeComprobante = m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("//cac:AdditionalItemProperty", manager)
       'TotalXML += Book.SelectSingleNode("//cac:AdditionalItemProperty", manager).InnerXml 'error
       'Dim mCodigo As Object = New Book.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name").Value 'error
   Next
   MessageBox.Show("Tota: " & TotalXML, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
```

Comment: You have a second XML file inside a CDATA section. You'll need to parse that separately

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would not know how to do it, can you tell me how or where I can find information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a second XML file inside a CDATA section. You'll need to parse that separately. Something like the code below. I can't test it because the XML you have included seems incomplete:

```
Dim m_xmld = New XmlDocument
Dim manager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
manager.AddNamespace("cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
manager.AddNamespace("cac", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2")
manager.AddNamespace("ext", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2")
m_xmld.Load(fileName)

Dim nodeDescription As XmlNode = m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("//cbc:Description", manager) 

Dim childDoc = New XmlDocument
childDoc.LoadXml(nodeDescription.FirstChild.InnerText.Trim) '<< parse the CDATA section
Dim additional = childDoc.SelectSingleNode("//cac:AdditionalItemProperty[0]")
MessageBox.Show(additional.InnerText, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
```

Comment: When executing with those changes, it shows me an error in the line childDoc.Load(nodeDescription.FirstChild.InnerText). Additional Information: Invalid characters in path.

Comment: Apologies, it should be `childDoc.LoadXml(nodeDescription.FirstChild.InnerText.Trim)`. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, the XML is now complete. With the new line it no longer throws an error in it, but it does in this MessageBox.Show(additional.InnerText.ToString, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
The error message it gives is:
"Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
In debug the value of the additional variable is Nothing

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to do the rest of the debugging yourself. The example XML you are providing isn't well-formed. You need to make sure every start tag has a matching end tag in your example

Comment: certainly, I edited it and recorded random information for confidential information issues